# Correct way to timeout asynchronous namedpipes in C# .net environoment

Tags: c#, asynchronous, ipc, named-pipes

I have a process that might have multiple instances running at anytime. Each instance should only run for several seconds at most.  A process might have to pass data to an earlier started instance, or receive data from a latter started instance using named pipes. Each instance is aware of each other, but doesn't know for sure if it will attempt to pass or receive data.  The process has a pipe server and client that each runs on its own thread.  Since the process doesn't know before hand if the other process needs to send or receive data, I need the ability to attempt a connection but to time out and close the pipe if it hasn't connected in a few seconds. I'm using the asynch NamedPipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection() method.  But I'm not sure if i'm using it correctly.

- The process starts with **Main()** creating a thread with the
  **receiveServer()** method.
- **receiveServer()** starts a NamedPipeServer in a ***using*** block and starts the BeginWaitForConnection() method.
- the **AsychWaitHandle(3000)** is used in the ***if*** condition so that if it successfully connects the **readMessage(namedPipeServer)** and a timeout timer is started.  If the **AsychWaitHandle(3000)** expires then control goes to the ***else*** block where ***NamedPipeServer.Close()*** method is called.
- The **holdtimer** runs as a safeguard while ***readMessage()*** method is running in case the pipeserver connects, and waits for data that never comes.  When ***holdtimer*** expires it calls and event handler that calls the pipe server's **close()** method.

Being new to some of this, my main questions and concerns with my code are the fact that **namedPipeServer.EndWaitForConnection(asynchResult)** is only called int the event that the connection succeeds.  According to the documentation EndWait must be called exacly once for each BeginWait.  Testing the application, if no connection is made in 3 seconds the logic just falls through to the else block and then the pipe is closed, sometimes twice with out throwing any exception.
I'm also concerned about the way that I use the **namedpipeserver.close()** method in the timeout event when there is a hangup.  That can call an exception **readMessage()** because the while loop tests ***while (!namedPipeServer.IsMessageComplete)***  which might be tested on a closed pipe.

I apologize for the lack of brevity, but I thought it would be a clearer question if I included all the relevant parts of the code.
Thanks in advance for the help.

```
    public static void readMessage(NamedPipeServerStream namedPipeServer)
    {
        //While block continues while the Read() method has not complete,
        // but once the Read() begins even if no data is available it blocks 
        //and the while block continues.  Which is the reason for the 
        //timeout.   
        {
            //Read from pipe to a global string variable
            namedPipeServer.Read(messageBuffer, 0, messageBuffer.Length);
        }
        while (!namedPipeServer.IsMessageComplete);
    }

    public static void receiveServer()
    {
        try
        {
            using (NamedPipeServerStream namedPipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("test-pipe", PipeDirection.InOut,
                1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous))
            {
                var asynchResult = namedPipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(null, null);

                //Adds a delegate to a timer that explicitly closes the pipe server on timeout
                holdtimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => clockExpired(sender, e, namedPipeServer));
                holdtimer.AutoReset = true;

                //If connection succeeds within 3 seconds
                //then control goes to the "if block"  where 
                //the read method is called. And the hold timer
                //is started.  If the connection doesn't succeed in 3
                //seconds then the named pipe server Close() method is called.    
                if (asynchResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(3000))
                {
                    //
                    namedPipeServer.EndWaitForConnection(asynchResult);
                    //start timer before calling method
                    holdtimer.Start();

                    //Pass namedAPipeServer to readMessage
                    readMessage(namedPipeServer);

                    //stop timer after method completes   
                    holdtimer.Stop();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("didn't get anything ----------");
                }

                //Explicately close the PipeServer.  
                namedPipeServer.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //This is just for testing.  
            MessageBox.Show("Exception in receiveMessage  :" + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //assign clockExpired() delgate to holdtimer
        Thread receiverThread = new Thread(receiveServer);
        receiverThread.Start();
    }
```